# colorbox highlighting: overfull hbox

Tags: line-breaking

For a current LaTeX-Document, I've done some highlighting using `colorbox`es around specific words or formulas. This works quite well, although, of course, the `colorbox` doesn't do line breaks when it is larger than the right border of the paper. Here is an example for that:
[image]

This is kinda annoying, especially, since I want to print that document. The `colorbox`es are of course done by a custom command, and I was wondering, if there's a way to improve that command, so that it **automatically add**s a **line break before the `colorbox`, when it gets too wide**. (e.g. when it would be set in the current position, it'd outstand the right border out the document). Is there any way to accomplish this?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Hello, could you show us a MWE ?

Comment: you could use `\raggedright`

Comment: Thank you, `\raggedright` did the trick ;)

Comment: You could have a look at the `soul` package.